# Mongoose failed to connect and Atlas MongoDB expect to whitelist IP while all IP has allowed

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ip

I hope someone could help me because I confused with this problem
I thought my code is OK but Atlas seems reject so I couldn't connect to Atlas. The connection so simple. I fill those params from nodemon.json:

```js
const {
    MONGODB_ATLAS_USERNAME,
    MONGODB_ATLAS_PASSWORD,
    MONGODB_ATLAS_DBNAME
} = process.env

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
app.listen(PORT, () => {
console.info(`App is running! at http://localhost:${PORT}`)
})   
mongoose.connect(`mongodb://${MONGODB_ATLAS_USERNAME}:${MONGODB_ATLAS_PASSWORD}@cluster0.lzjty.mongodb.net/${MONGODB_ATLAS_DBNAME}?retryWrites=true&w=majority&ssl=true`,{useNewUrlParser:true,useUnifiedTopology:true});
```

On Atlas, I whitelisted my IP and allow all IP to connect
[image]
But every npm run, the return always:

```
    App is running! at http://localhost:8080
[1] (node:2012) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/
```

Comment: Are you using your public IP? Just asking because I have seen people do this before

Comment: Sure, but if i use non public IP, shouldn't it already be able to connect by using 0.0.0.0/0 ?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I added &tls=true and it worked.

Comment: This is correct answer. Insecure connections are dropped so either use `&tls=true` as you suggested or pass `ssl: true` in the configuration.

Answer (score -1):

It generally happens when you use public IP. It changes every time you connect to the internet and you need to make changes to the MONGO Atlas. I would suggest you make these changes for development.

Follow this:- `MongoDB Atlas` -> `NetworkAccess` -> `Edit` -> `Allow Any`

Comment: It would be a great idea if downvote can be explained to give a better answer.

Comment: yes I already use Allow any. So you can look 0.0.0.0 on my picture but I still cannot connect